# Prove that if $H \leq G$ has exactly $k$ conjugates in $G$ then there exists a homomoprihsm $\alpha: G \rightarrow S_k$ such that....

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Prove that if $H \leq G$ has exactly $k$ conjugates in $G$ then there exists a homomoprihsm $\alpha: G \rightarrow S_k$ such that $k$ divides $im(\alpha)$

Proof: Let $G$ act on the set of conjugates of $H$ in $G$. This induces a homomorphism $\alpha: G \rightarrow S_k$

If we can find an element of $g$ that maps to an element of order $k$ in $S_k$ we are done.

Now, the action of $G$ on the set of conjugates of $H$ is transitive. Let us denote these conjugates by the set $\{a_1,a_2,....a_k\}$

Then $\exists g_2 \in G$ s.t. $\alpha(g) = (1,2)$

and

$\exists g_3 \in G$ s.t. $\alpha(g) = (1,3)$

$\exists g_4 \in G$ s.t. $\alpha(g) = (1,4)$

....

$\exists g_k \in G$ s.t. $\alpha(g) = (1,k)$

Then $\alpha(g_k....g_3g_2)=(1,k)...(1,3)(1,2)$

which is an element of order $k$ in $im(\alpha)$

Comment: Why is there $g_i$ such that $\alpha(g_i)$ is a transposition?

Comment: $P$ transitive of degree $k$, then $P/P_\alpha$ has cardinality $k$.

Comment: Ah, good question. Dang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Use orbit-stabilizer and the first isomorphism theorem.

Recall that if $K\le H \le G$, then

$$[G:K] = [G:H][H:K].$$

---

Now that you have the problem mostly worked out in the comments, I want to give a full solution here in case that helps.

Let $G$ act on the set of conjugates of $H$ by conjugation. Set $O_H$ to be the orbit of $H$, and $G_H$ to be the stabilizer subgroup of $H$. Note that since this is a transitive action, $|O_H| = k$, and thus

$$|G/G_H| = [G:G_H] = |O_H| = k.$$

Now, we want to understand $|\operatorname{im}(\alpha)| = |G/\ker(\alpha)| = [G:\ker(\alpha)]$. Note that if $g\in\ker(\alpha)$ then $g$ stabilizes all conjugates of $H$ — and in particular $H$ itself — and thus $g\in G_H$. Therefore, we see that $\ker(\alpha)\le G_H$. This implies that

$$|\operatorname{im}(\alpha)| = [G:\ker(\alpha)] = [G:G_H][G_H:\ker(\alpha)] = k\cdot[G_H:\ker(\alpha)].$$

This implies that $k$ divides $|\operatorname{im}(\alpha)|$.

Comment: so $\frac{G}{ker(\alpha)} \cong im(\alpha) \leq S_k$.

I do not see why it is obvious from here.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom Now apply obit stabilizer to that situation.

Comment: Man, sorry i'm confused. Have $G$ act on $im(\alpha)$ maybe? Then for each $x \in im(\alpha)$, $|Orb(x)| = |\frac{G}{G_x}|$...Cool, still not seeing the light at the end of the tunnel though, haha >.<.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom we want to have G act on H and it’s conjugates by conjugation. Then, how large is the orbit? How is the index of the kernel related to the index of the stabilizer subgroup?

Comment: The action is transitive and so the orbit is any element of the set has cardinality $k$.  The stabilizer subgroup is all the elements of $G$ that fix a certain element of the set being acted upon, and the kernel is the elements of $G$ that fix every element in the set being acted upon, so one might expect the stabilizer of an element to big larger than the kernel. 

I do not know how to get division involved, though.

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom you almost have it. Think about the kernel and the stabilizer subgroup and apply this statement about their indexes in my answer. What does orbit stabilizer say that the index of the stabilizer subgroup is in G?

Comment: $|orbit(a_1)| = k = [G:G_x]=[G:ker(\alpha)][ker(\alpha):G_x]$

where $[G:ker(\alpha)] = |im(\alpha)|$. So if i can show that $[ker(\alpha):G_x] >1$ then I am done.

This good?

If so, any hints on showing $[ker(\alpha):G_x] >1$ ??

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom I went ahead and typed out the solution I had in mind. Hopefully that makes things clear. Let me know if you have anymore questions!

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom You should point out to yourself exactly where each of the three facts in my hint are being used. Where am I using orbit-stabilizer, where am I using the first isomorphism theorem, and where I am using the fact that nested indexes multiply?